# How to send HTTP POST parameters using Android AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: android, node.js, express, http-post, android-async-http

I am trying the [`AsyncHttpClient`](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library for Android and am trying to make a HTTP POST with it to my Express (NodeJS) server and I am having difficulties attaching parameters to the POST request.

This is what I do:

```
AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
requestParams.put("username", usernameEditText.getText().toString());
requestParams.put("password", passwordEditText.getText().toString());
httpClient.post("http://1.2.3.4/sign-up", requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    // here I override the onSuccess and onFailure methods
}
```

But when the request comes to the Express server, I can't find the parameters anywhere. I was used to finding the POST parameters in `req.body`, but:

```
app.post('/sign-up', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username; // throws error because req.body is undefined
});
```

Is the [`AsyncHttpClient`](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library broken or am I doing something wrong on either side?

Comment: Hm, it seems like there might be something wrong with the Express server because the same thing happens if I send a POST request there using `curl`. Will investigate and post an answer myself if I find something out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware.

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Yes, you are of course right. However, I wonder why they removed it from Express itself. I know it had its issues, but aren't POST requests kind of useless without that?

Comment: Not all http servers need to handle post requests.

Comment: Yes, I know. My point is that why is it even possible to do `app.post` without the `body-parser` since it won't work properly anyway? Nevermind.

Comment: It will work without body-parser. And you could always parse the post contents yourself or use a different module. https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable